# Obtain data from CoreData to make calculations

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data, nsarray

I'm working on my first application, and I'm slowly learning the objective-c. But now I'm stuck. The application calculates the number of days between two dates, and so far so good. But now I would give the possibility to create groups of holidays which will go to escape from the total bill. I created two entities with a CoreData for the group and the other for the holidays of the group (see photo). How do I get the dates included in the code of my application to make the necessary calculations?
[image]

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do?

Comment: hello, see the two dates in the picture? I need to get them to perform calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to calculate the distance between dates, use this.

```
NSDate *date1;
NSDate *date2;
NSTimeInterval timeBetweenDates = [date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1];
```

`NSTimeInterval` is just a `#typedef` for `double`.

If you are trying to make other calculations, please give some examples.

Comment: Hello Jeff. I made a code that calculates the number of days between two dates, just as you have written in your answer. Now I need to subtract (only when the dates entered in the table of the photo is in the range of dates) dates of the photos. Example: from the 01/12/2012 to 31/12/2012 there are 31 days, now I have to subtract 31 to 25/12/2012 (date to be inserted in the table).

Comment: Well, you just subtract 1 from the total number of days right?

Comment: So, isn't that the solution to the problem then?